# Custom Filter missing on Security Filter Chain

Tags: security, filter, chain

I have a simple Security Config with one CustomFilter(MyAuthorizationFilter) added before FilterSecurityInterceptor.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true) 
@Profile({ "local", "test" }) 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true) 
@EnableResourceServer 
public class SecurityLocalConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override   
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new MyAuthorizationFilter(), FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);           
    }

}
```

I see it in the logs when application is started.

> 2019-08-02 12:31:59.090  INFO 74924 --- [  restartedMain]
> o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any
> request,
> [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@28d34c24,
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4787d4da,
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2219138f,
> org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@2042e42,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@518b63cb,
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@20d72122,
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@4ab8dbdc,
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3114a62d,
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@29a651d9,
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4d655a42,
> com.test.cash.http.filters.**MyAuthorizationFilter**@3dfefde8]

However **MyAuthorizationFilter** is missing in the security chain,  when I make API call. I am not sure what is that I am going wrong with?

```
Security filter chain: [
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  LogoutFilter
  OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same question before. My situation is that it creates two filter chains that one of it contains the original 11 filters, another one contains original 11 filters and custom filters. It is possible that you use annotation @EnableResourceServer which will automatically build the filter chains of those 11 filters with higher order.